# How to convert std::string to v8's Local<string>

Tags: c++, string, v8

I have a function which is ment to take in a string and then pass it to my c++ function `add_node()`

```
Handle<Value> Graph::add_node(const v8::Arguments& args)
{
  HandleScope scope;

  Graph* graph = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Graph>(args.This());
  graph->add_node( args[0]->ToString() );

  std::cout << "In add node \n";
}
```

However I'm having trouble because all of my arguments are v8 templetes of some sort or another and I cant figure out how to switch between the two. The [documentation](http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1String.html) doesn't state it clearly either.

The compiler is giving me this error

```
../graph/binding.cc:52:10: error: no matching member function for call to
      'add_node'
  graph->add_node( args[0]->ToString() );
  ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
../graph/directed_graph.h:27:7: note: candidate function not viable: no known
      conversion from 'Local<v8::String>' to 'std::string &' (aka
      'basic_string<char> &') for 1st argument;
        void add_node( std::string & currency );
```

How can I switch between `Local<v8::String>` and `std::string &`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This seems to work well

```
v8::String::Utf8Value param1(args[0]->ToString());
std::string from = std::string(*param1);
```

and if you're trying to convert a `std::string` to a `v8::String` then do

```
std::string something("hello world"); 
Handle<Value> something_else = String::New( something.c_str() );
```

Comment: Later versions of v8 need a slightly different approach: ```String::NewFromUtf8( isolate,  something.c_str() )```

Comment: Something for the year 2020? All these answers don't work for node 12

Comment: yes， when i try this，
i get an error
error: no matching member function for call to 'ToString'

Answer (score 2):

I don't have that v8 framework on this box, but this

```
v8::AsciiValue av(args[0]->ToString());
std::basic_string<char> str(av);
graph->add_node(str);
```

should work, given graph->add_node copies the str.

Comment: `AsciiValue` is not in `v8` namespace anymore, but in `v8::String::AsciiValue`.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Mar 2020 (NodeJS v12.16.1):

```
using v8::Local;
using v8::String;
using v8::NewStringType;

std::string encoded_val = **some_value**;

Local<String> returned_str = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, encoded_val.c_str(), 
NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked();
```

Comment: how to change v8 string to c++ string